# bash script to read my files and execute the command

Tags: bash

I have a script which one can run as ./analyze file.txt file.root log.txt 
file.txt is input file which contains executable root files with their paths, others are output. My problem is I have almost 30 input files and i do not want to write down the command each time to run the code. Bash script would be nice but I did not manage. It gives an error. see an example of the code below, I try to run:

```
  #!/bin/bash

do

echo

./analyze runlist1.txt runlist1.root log1.txt

./analyze runlist2.txt runlist2.root log.txt

./analyze runlist3.txt runlist3.root log.txt

./analyze runlist4.txt runlist4.root res4.txt

done
```

I get the error "syntax error near unexpected token `do' ", Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you just cut some code. `do` / `done` itself do nothing, they are part of for cycle for example
`for i in 1 2 3; do echo $1; done`
just remove it from your script

Comment: @vlp yes I am no good in bash. But you are right so does it work to use sth like > cat runlist1.txt  |while read myline and ./analyze {$myline} ?

Comment: Yes, but use `./analyze ${myline}`. I suppose runlist1.txt has lines with the inputfile and two outputfiles for each analyze call.

Comment: @WalterA yes right. I modified the code now will write it as an answer because it's too long to write as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all files are called Brunsplit.txt, the following will help

```
for file in Brunsplit*.txt; do
   tmp=${file%.txt}
   nr=${tmp#Brunsplit}
   ./analyze ${file} runlist${nr}.root res${nr}.txt
done
```

The tmp and nr vars are filled with special syntax, it is something like cutting off .txt at the end and Brunsplit from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Like others indicated in comments, the `do` out of context is a syntax error (it is a valid keyword right after a `for`, `while`, and `until` control statement).

Apparently, there is no systematic mapping between input file names and the corresponding log file names, so you need a script which maintains this mapping.  Something like this, then:

```
while read suffix logfile; do
    ./analyze "runlist$suffix.txt" "runlist$suffix.root" "$logfile"
done <<'____HERE'
    1 log1.txt
    2 log.txt
    3 log.txt
    4 res4.txt
____HERE
```

The here document (the stuff between `<<` *delimiter* and the *delimiter* alone on a line) is just like a text file, except it is embedded as part of the script.

Comment: Wow! Thanks tripleee this answer is beyond my logic, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out the primitive but the modified version.

> !/bin/bash
>
> for file in Brunsplit1.txt Brunsplit2.txt
>
> do
>
> echo $file
>
> ./analyze Brunsplit1.txt runlist1.root res1.txt
>
> ./analyze Brunsplit2.txt runlist2.root res2.txt
>
> done

Thanks.

Comment: In each loop you will analyze both files. When the numbering is this simple, just use `for nr in 1 2; do ./analyze Brunsplit${nr} runlist${nr}.root res${nr}.txt; done`. More difficult: look at solution of @tripleee.